# Can't get toLocaleString() to work

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to use toLocaleString() in these two small scripts. I've tried different takes, but nothing seem to work. Could anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    var total_span = 0;
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
      total_span += this.checked && +this.value; 
    });

   $({counter: + $('#total').text()}).animate({counter: total_span},{
     duration: 1000,
     easing: 'swing',
     step: function () {
       $('#total').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
       $('#total-2').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
     },
     complete : function(){
       $('#total').text(total_span.toLocaleString("sv-SE"));
       $('#total-2').text(total_span.toLocaleString("sv-SE"));
     }
   }); 
  });   
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(':radio').change(function (e) {
    //clear the div
    $('#final').html('');
    //update the div
    $(':radio:checked').each(function (ind, ele) {
        $('#final').append('<div><h4>' + $(ele).attr("name") + ':</h4>' + $(ele).attr("id") + '<br />' + $(ele).val().toLocaleString("sv-SE") + ':-<br/></div>');
    });
  });
});
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could please let me know how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: To solve what!? What are you trying to do? What are the expected results? What are you getting instead?

Comment: If you can just put your code into fiddle and give us the link.... Also will be great to get some more info as @Teemu said
Also to understand how to use toLocaleString just read these 2
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: @AlexanderSashaShcherbakov - a snippet HERE at SO is better

Comment: Please  click the `<>` in the editor and provide a [mcve] and explain what expected result is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this? toLocaleString seems to work as expected

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var total_span = 0;
    $('#final').empty(); // same as .html("")
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() { // Only take the checked radios
      var val = +this.value; // the + makes the value numeric if it is a number
      val = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val; // check it IS a number
      total_span += val; // and add it
      $('#final').append('<div><h4>' + this.name + ':</h4>' + this.id + '<br />' + val.toLocaleString("sv-SE") + ':-<br/></div>');
    });
    $({
      counter: +$('#total').text()
    }).animate({
      counter: total_span
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function() {
        $('#total').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
        $('#total-2').text(Math.floor(this.counter));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('#total').text(total_span.toLocaleString("sv-SE"));
        $('#total-2').text(total_span.toLocaleString("sv-SE"));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
100.01 <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="rad1" value="100.01" /><br />
200.02 <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="rad2" value="200.02" /><br />
300.03 <input type="radio" name="rad3" id="rad3" value="100.03" /><br />
<div id="final"></div>
Total <span id="total"></span>
Total-2 <span id="total-2"></span>
```

Comment: This works perfect! So, I can see your changes, but can't really understand why they make it all work. Could you please explain? Would have been very kind of you!

Comment: I added some comments. I did not comment the code you already had